# Wordpress: wp_mail() not working on main domain but works on sub domains

Tags: php, wordpress

I run several websites on one server and for some reason I cant seem to use wp_mail to send emails through my main domain. Every other domain and new domains I create work but not the main domain. Ive tried using several plugins including wp-mail-smtp but unfortunately I cant get my main domain to send mail using the wp_mail function. I can use the mail() function but this isnt ideal and I heard it can be easily hacked. I wrote a script to test the wp_mail function:

```
<?php
/

**
 * This file can be used to validate that the WordPress wp_mail() function is working.
 * To use, change the email address in $to below, save, and upload to your WP root.
 * Then browse to the file in your browser.
 */

// Set $to as the email you want to send the test to
$to = "support@XXXXX.com.au";

// No need to make changes below this line

// Email subject and body text
$subject = 'wp_mail function test';
$message = 'This is a test of the wp_mail function: wp_mail is working';
$headers = 'no-reply@xxxx.com.au';

// Load WP components, no themes
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('wp-load.php');

// send test message using wp_mail function
$sent_message = wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );

//display message based on the result.
if ( $sent_message ) {
    // the message was sent...
    echo 'The test message was sent. Check your email inbox.';
} else {
    // the message was not sent...
    echo 'The message was not sent!';
}
```

This function seems to work with my sub-domains but not with my main domain. The error message just says message not sent. Is there a way I can test wp_mail better? Maybe get a more meaningful error message that can help me pin-point the problem code? My hosting provider insist its a wordpress issue.

Kind Regards

UPDATE:
So i've reinstalled my core wordpress files and the problem is still there.

UPDATED CODE:

```
<?php
/**
 * This file can be used to validate that the WordPress wp_mail() function is working.
 * To use, change the email address in $to below, save, and upload to your WP root.
 * Then browse to the file in your browser.
 */

// Set $to as the email you want to send the test to
$to = "support@xxxxx.com.au";

// No need to make changes below this line

// Email subject and body text
$subject = 'wp_mail function test';
$message = 'This is a test of the wp_mail function: wp_mail is working';
$headers = 'no-reply@xxxx.com.au';

// Load WP components, no themes
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('wp-load.php');
add_action('wp_mail_failed', 'print_r');
// send test message using wp_mail function
$sent_message = wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );

//display message based on the result.
if ( $sent_message ) {
    // the message was sent...
    echo 'Message Sent';
} else {
    // the message was not sent...
     echo 'Message Not Sent';

}
```

Comment: Your headers are wrong. No need a field before the no-reply address.

Comment: Do the files have the correct permissions?

Comment: Yeah that isnt the issue since i have tested the mail() function in a different script and that seems to work fine. That script is in the same directory as the script above.

Comment: @Chris What should the headers be? This script works fine on my sub-domains, do I need extra header info for my main domain? As in more info since its a main domain and not a sub-domain. Keep in my mind my sub-domains are website names that are different from the main domain. I think its called shared hosting if im not mistaken

Comment: I'm not saying it's necessarily what's causing your problem, just that you need to specify a field name. At a guess I'd say you probably want `From:`.

Comment: Like this @Chris 'From: The Admin <no-reply@xxxx.com.au>';
Sorry not sure how to put code in comments

Comment: Yes, that would be correct. You can put code in comments by surrounding it with backticks by the way `\`like this\``.

Comment: @Chris `From: The Admin <no-reply@xxxx.com.au>;` Didnt work. Still says message not sent

Comment: Okay, to get a more detailed error message you need to hook in to the `wp_mail_failed` action. Maybe try adding `add_action('wp_mail_failed', 'print_r');` to the top of your code and see if you get a more detailed error.

Comment: TY @Chris do I need to enclose my code in a function now or can I just add this straight to the script?

Comment: You should be able to put that straight in (after your `require` line actually, rather than right at the top of the script).

Comment: Ah Thanks @Chris so to print out the errors from print_r do i need to print it out as a variable as in `echo $print_r`, is it an array and how can I display this message when I run the script. Also do i still use wp_mail to send the message for the test or do i change it to wp_mail_failed?

Comment: No, just put the code in as is. `print_r` is a function that (with that code) will be called whenever sending a mail fails. It should output the details of the message itself. Leave the `wp_mail` function the same.

Comment: Sorry @chris I still Feel like a fool, so after `wp_mail();` should I have nothing written so that print_r can display the error?

Comment: It shouldn't matter if you leave the `echo`s in, since they will just be printed after the error.

Comment: Well the only error message is `Message Not Sent`. Am I doing something Wrong? Look at the update in my question for my updated Code

Comment: Which version of WordPress are you using? It looks like the `wp_mail_failed` action was added in 4.4.0.

Comment: The version just before 4.50. Which i believe is the latest one. I cant update to the latest version because there are java script errors I need to fix first.

Comment: Could you try taking the `;` out from the end of your headers line and see if that fixes it?

Comment: @chris No Luck, script wont run at all when I do that

Comment: Zayd, to clarify, I meant the one in the string, not the one right at the end of the line.

Comment: @Chris I removed the ':' and still only the Message Not Sent line comes up. I've fixed my JS errors on the site and have now updated to 4.5 of wordpress

Comment: I don't think I've got any more ideas then. Sorry :(

Comment: Awww, I appreciate the help. Maybe a wordpress genius can solve this issue at some point down the line. Look I still feel like my hosting company did something with my MX records and thats when the problem started happening. I've escalated the problem and hopefully someone helps me out. Thanks for the effort @chris :)

Answer (score 0):

Try change the header of the email. Add or change the form attribute to a subdomain like "norepy@email.domain.com" instead of "noreply@domain.com"